# String interpolation inside string interpolation

Tags: c#, string-interpolation, c#-6.0

Is it possible to have a variable with a string format that you would like interpolated.

```
public class Setting
{
    public string Format { get; set; }
}


var setting = new Setting { Format = "The car is {colour}" };
var colour = "black";
var output = $"{setting.Format}";
```

Expected output

> "The car is black".

Comment: Use `string.Format`. if you have variables and not constants. and you can't have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: People have written a bunch of extension methods for this purpose.   [`FormatWith`](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables) or a similar.  Be warned that every one of these custom functions has [slightly different behavior](https://web.archive.org/web/20131203044747/http://blog.dotnetwiki.org/2009/01/16/NamedFormatsPexTestimonium.aspx).  See also [Named Formats Redux](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/14/named-formats-redux.aspx/).

Answer (score 10):

You can't do that.  String interpolation is a purely compile-time feature.

Answer (score 5):

No you can't do that, but you can achieve the same with a slightly different approach, that I've come to like:

```
public class Setting
{
    public Func<string, string> Format { get; set; }
}
```

then you can pass your string argument to `Format`:

```
var setting = new Setting { Format = s => $"The car is {s}" };
var output = setting.Format("black");
```

Comment: Which the compiler basically turns into `Setting { Format = s => string.Format("The car is {0}", s) };`

Answer (score 3):

Why not?
First of all, you can't use a local variable before declaring it in C#. So
First declare the `colour` before using it. Then "interpolate" the string assigned to `Format` and you are done.

```
var colour = "black";
var setting = new Setting { Format = $"The car is {colour}" };
var output = $"{setting.Format}";
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Output:

> The car is black.

Comment: I like this, but can you elaborate for future readers since your change is so subtle?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a slight alteration on it, like the following:

```
public class Setting
{
    public string Format
    { 
        get
        {
            return String.Format(this.Format, this.Colour);
        }
        set
        {
            Format = value;
        }
    }

    public string Colour { get; set; }
}


var setting = new Setting { Format = "The car is {0}", Colour = "black" };
```

Then the output will be "The car is black".

I haven't tested this code.