# $ - string interpolation compile in real time - from file

Tags: c#

I have a file ( or can be a NVARCHAR in column in DB)
the string is

```
   $"My name is {Name}"
```

so in my code it should be

```
   var Name = "Donald";
   var line = //Get line from file or DB
   var output = $"{line}"; //<-??????
```

line will actually will be = "$"My name is {Name}""; when viewing in debug mode

It's look like a big no no when I looked at that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829410/string-interpolation-inside-string-interpolation)
I want to avoid using string.Format (ex:"My Name is (0)")

Comment: You might get close with `line.Replace($"{{{nameof(Name)}}}", Name)` and removing the starting `$"` and the closing `"`

Comment: You'll have to stick with String.Format or manually substitute tokens for values (or maybe there is a library which does that in sensible way).

Comment: you probably don't want to work with a replace function ? you want the replaced variable handled by the file content and don't bother with it in the code? is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

As SLag mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33829459/2528063), string-interpolation is a **compiletime**-feature. Generally the compiler will transform your string into some `String.Format`. So `$"MyString { line }`  will result in `String.Format("MyString {0}", line)`.

However in your case `line` itself is an interpolated string itself. So the compiler will transform it into this:

```
var output = string.Format("{0}", line);
```

which is evaluated at **runtime**. So the compiler has no clue about the actual value and therefor about the fact that it must be translated *again.*